# linear combination of projections

Tags: linear-algebra

Let G be the group of all  matrices of all linear combination of projection maps with respect to multiplication. Has this group any interesting property?

Comment: You need to be more precise. As it stands, this doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

The algebras generated by projections (which is what you are constructing) are quite interesting; in particular, this is a property of von Neumann algebras. See [Is a von Neumann algebra just a C*-algebra which is generated by its projections?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115160/is-a-von-neumann-algebra-just-a-c-algebra-which-is-generated-by-its-projections)

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ and $Q$ are projection to disjoint spaces, then $PQ=QP=0$. So even as a monoid it is not very interesting (at least to me!)

In any case if $P$ is a projection and $P\ne I$ then $P$ is singular. Proof:
$$
P^2 = P \Rightarrow P (P-I) = 0
$$

Comment: This is false unless the subspaces are orthogonal.