# Classification of $C^*$ algebras whose subalgebra generated by projections is a von neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115160/is-a-von-neumann-algebra-just-a-c-algebra-which-is-generated-by-its-projections) we ask the following question:

Is there a  complete classification of  all unital  $C^*$  algebra $A$ for which the following  subalgebra $B$ is  a  von Neumann algebra? Is there  a  terminology for such kind  of  $C^*$  algebras?

$$B=\text{The unital $C^*$ sub algebra  generated  by all  projections of $A$} $$

Of course every  von neumann algebra  satisfies this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not at all. Infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebras are non-separable as C$^*$-algebras, so for separable C$^*$-algebras (the ones one cares about) only trivial examples (i.e., finite-dimensional) are available. That will happen for instance when $A$ is projectionless and unital, where $B=\mathbb C$.